# send build status from jenkins to gitlab webhooks

Tags: jenkins, build, gitlab, webhooks

I am trigger a webhook in gitlab once Merge request is raised, where I call a jenkins job to do a build on the pulled code.

Now my requirement is I need to send the build status/jenkins console link back to gitlab, so the reviewer can easily see what the issue is in the code and reject/approve the MR.

I tried googling a lot but I am not able to find any solution.